# Java parsing from string to numeric but infer type

Tags: java, string

I am trying to write a generic method converting a string to number. Which API can I use to finish this.

```
private <T extends Number> T parseFromString(String str) {
   // convert str to number
}
```

Then call :

```
   parseFromString<Double>("120.0");

   parseFromString<Integer>("11");
```

Comment: It's not possible. The type of `T` is unknown at runtime.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend thinking again about why you need this sort of API, because in general, trying to do generics over different kinds of numbers is almost always a bad plan.

Comment: I have to echo Louis's concern here. I certainly write code capable of doing this, but I promise you there is a better way to solve the problem you're encountering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use generic, I would just use :

```
private static Number parseFromString(String str) throws NumberFormatException {
    if (str.matches("\\d+")) {
        return Integer.valueOf(str);
    } else if (str.matches("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+")) {
        return Double.valueOf(str);
    }
    throw new NumberFormatException("Number not correct");
}
```

Outputs

```
System.out.println(parseFromString("11"));    // 11
System.out.println(parseFromString("112.3")); // 112.3
System.out.println(parseFromString("some not correct strings")); // Number not correct
```

---

Or as [@shmosel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55384803/java-parsing-from-string-to-numeric-but-infer-type#comment97491900_55385015) mentioned in his comment, you can just use :

```
private static Number parseFromString(String str) throws ParseException {
    return NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(str);
}
```

In this solution you may lose precision, so it may required to use locale, like so :

```
private static Number parseFromString(String str) throws ParseException {
    return NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.CANADA).parse(str);
}
```

Comment: Or just use `NumberFormat`.

Comment: @shmosel how to use `NumberFormat` in this case?

Comment: `return NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(str);`

Comment: @shmosel thank you for the solution it is more simple